# Is there a word for a person who makes wind instruments?

Tags: nouns, music

There's the word *luthier* for a string instrument maker, but with winds, the only option seem to be more like naming something in modern English, like "reedmaker" which would more apply to double reed instrument players who make their own reeds or something like "wind luthier" even though that's the best option as far as I can tell.